# In javascript or css, how to detect if an elements is over-hidden by some of his parents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image: the problem]

As you see in my page, almost every **red** was hidden by the parents, but some **reds** was not.

I want to use javascript (or jquery) to detect the error **reds** and change their postion to the easy-view position.

Please help me!

**UPDATE 1: trying to use css, but still have errors**

Thanks **Buzinas** and **charlietfl**, but:

I can use css to select all red, but when i move them down a bit, they over-hide the text of a link, so at some links, we can not read the first word. As you see in the image below:

[image: a busy cat]

**UPDATE 2: running testing page**

Page: http://mp3.zing.vn/

To show **reds**, you should run these code in your console:

```
        sohientai = 1
        $("body").append("<style>.bstalktochrome_btn {display:none}.bstalktochrome {font-size: 9px;padding: 0px 1px !important;font-weight: bold;max-width: 40px;position: absolute !important;top: -3px !important;left: 0px !important;line-height: normal;z-index:100000;background-color: rgba(236, 2, 2, 0.7) !important; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) !important;margin: 0px !important;} [data-talktochrome]{position:relative !important;} </style>")
        $("a").each(function(){
            $(this).prepend('<span class="bstalktochrome" title="'+sohientai+'">'+sohientai+'</span>')
            $(this).attr("data-talktochrome", sohientai)
            sohientai++
        })
```

**UPDATE 3 : Diptox & Hieu Le**

> So awkward those red stuff , why you want them , if you don't mind ? and for me i saw all of them correctly displayed

For every links or button of a page, i will insert an unique helper number for them **(the reds)**. So the user can use that helper number to interact with the links on the page.

The problem at this time is some **reds** displayed but cover some first characters of their links, so the user can not read some them correctly **or** some **reds** is hidden by their parents.

I just want to show **reds**, that the user can read the number of **reds** and also can read the link text without any advanced too.

Comment: You should be fixing that with CSS, imho.

Comment: You need to inspect the elements themselves in browser dev tools to see the css rules that apply to those specific elements and adjust accordingly. There is no way to tell you what script would help without being able to see the live html...and css should fix it anyway

Comment: Please help me with the two UPDATEs in my question.

Comment: they are margined outside of elements with `overflow:hidden`. Can see them clearly when you toggle that property in dev tools css inspector

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with those reds.

Comment: So awkward those red stuff , why you want them , if you don't mind ?
and for me i saw all of them correctly displayed

Comment: **Update 3** explain what i want to do with these reds.